# How to make an overlay with round edges (iPhone SDK)?

Tags: iphone, uiview, sdk, view, overlay

I've just received a lot of good responses to the question about making overlay views.
[Is there a way that I can make an overlay view on the iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253334/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-make-an-overlay-view-on-the-iphone-sdk)

Another question I have is how to make an overlay view have round edges like in the Skype iPhone app or in the Phone.app.

Thanks.

Comment: If my answer did solve your problem, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use these helper functions and then mask/clip to the resulting `CGPath`:

http://fabian-kreiser.com/index.php?id=1135350598525812781

Or use `view.layer.cornerRadius`, as seen in [How do I create a round cornered UILabel on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510382/how-do-i-create-a-round-cornered-uilabel-on-the-iphone/512402).

Comment: This blog post I wrote might help too: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Comment: i find this is good
http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2010/08/add-rounded-corners-and-border-to.html

Answer (score 4):

Use the view.layer's cornerRadius property.

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

...

```
overlayView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```