# grouped table view with Loren Brichter's fast scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using Loren Brichter's tweetie fast scroll where he draws out the entire cell in draw rect.  When I set the table view style to grouped, the cell gets the right inset but does not get a rounded corner.  Is there a preferred method to get a rounder corner cell using Brichter's fast scroll?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one line per section you could add something like

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

to your `initWithFrame:` (or something similar) of your `cellView`.

It's more difficult if you need only some of the corners do be round. But this question has been answered a couple of times. You could use the code from the following question in your `drawRect`:

[Rounded UIView using CALayers - only some corners - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how)