# Custom background drawing in an grouped UITableViewCell

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, quartz-graphics, cagradientlayer

I'm having some trouble drawing a custom gradient background in a `UITableViewCell` when the style is set to 'grouped' and the cell is first or the last one of the section. My approach is to simply create a `CAGradientLayer` and add it to the view like this:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = rect;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[_backgroundColorLight CGColor], (id)[_backgroundColorDark CGColor], nil];
[self.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
self.backgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Unfortunately this produces cells like this one:[image: Background exceeding the edges]

Does anyone have a hint on how to make the background fit the boarders of the cell?

Thanks
–f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw a custom background, you also have to draw the borders yourself. There's quite some open source stuff out there.

Basically, you need to know [in the cell] if it's top/middle/bottom/single, and cut the stuff in drawRect. You won't come far with insertSublayer.

Check out the PageCellBackground class you find here:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html

Comment: Great, that's seems to be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but CAGradientLayer happens to be a subclass of CALayer, so perhaps setting its borderRadius may work. But it rounds all corners then, so you may compensate for that by making the layer bigger than the cell and have the cell view cut it off.

Look at [Rounded UIView using CALayers - only some corners - How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how) for more examples