# Properly masking CALayers

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, cashapelayer, tapku

I am using the TapkuLibrary's otherwise excellent [TKCalendarDayEventView](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/blob/master/src/TapkuLibrary/TKCalendarDayEventView.m) and trying to selectively round one of the corners in the view as [StuDev demonstrates here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how). Unfortunately, applying StuDev's code snippet results in the EventView disappearing entirely from its containing TKCalendarDayTimelineView. I am adding this code snippet underneath the current code in the

`+ (id)eventViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame id:(NSNumber *)id startDate:(NSDate *)startDate endDate:(NSDate *)endDate title:(NSString *)title location:(NSString *)location;`

method. I have commented out code that otherwise sets the border width, color, or radius in the code. I have made sure that TKCalendarDayEventView doesn't have any superlayers, since the 
apple docs warn against adding masks to layers with superlayers:

> When setting the mask to a new layer, the new layer’s superlayer must first be set to nil, otherwise the behavior is undefined.

I have also tried playing around with the backgroundColor and fillColor properties of the maskLayer. I don't see anything in the TKCalendarDayEventView that might stop this mask from being correctly applied. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I have just pushed a codefile out as a demonstration of what is happnening [here](https://github.com/aashidham/TapkuCalDemo). [The offending file is here](https://github.com/aashidham/TapkuCalDemo/blob/master/TKCalendarDayEventView.m), beginning in line 76 and ending in line 95.

Comment: I downloaded the test code that you posted as a comment under your question. Commenting out the masking code (lines 76-96 in TKCalendarDayEventView.m) doesn't appear to have any effect on the view, and so it would appear the problem could lie elsewhere. What made you suspect this code was causing the problem?

Comment: Hey StuDev! Thanks for your help! :) The reason you are not seeing a difference in views is because the timeline application is displaying events on Jan 2 2012 (today), of which there are none. The difference in the views is seen if you press the back arrow, to go to Jan 1, 2012, to see a difference. I have also pushed a commit to the repo so that Jan 1 2012 is displayed by default. Pull that commit, or go to Jan 1 2012, and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint in your `eventViewWithFrame:id:startDate:endDate:title:location:` method, you will see that when you create your event view you are setting the frame to `CGRectZero`. The code snippet that then sets the rounded corner mask is using `CGRectZero` as the mask layer's frame.

Probably the simplest way to deal with this would be to override `TKCalendarDayEventView`'s `setFrame:` method like so:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame
{
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect([super frame], newFrame)) {
        [super setFrame:newFrame];

        // Change the view's mask layer to fit the new frame.
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds 
                                                       byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft
                                                             cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(15.0, 15.0)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
}
```

This way, every time you change the frame of the view the mask automatically adjusts.