# How to round only corners on a UITableView?

Tags: ios, rounded-corners, uibezierpath, uitableview

I am trying to round only the top right and left corners of my tableview. I am using the code below and it only seems to be rounding the top left corner...

```
CAShapeLayer *topLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *roundedPath = 
[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.f, 9.0f)];    
topLayer.path = [roundedPath CGPath];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5826698/855738 I used this answer to do pretty much the same thing

Comment: Know its an old post but just make sure youve got. [tableView.layer setMasksToBound: YES] and it should be fine and dandy

Comment: See the accepted answer [here][1]. It may be the same issue. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934231/uiview-in-cell-cant-round-right-hand-corners

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work. 
Find the top corner paths to create a mask layer

```
UIBezierPath *PathToMask;
PathToMask = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.testView.bounds
                                 byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];
```

Create a shape layer mask using the UIBezierPath maskPath

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init]; 
maskLayer.frame =self.testView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = PathToMask.CGPath;
```

set the mask layer maskLayer

```
self.testView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```