# Round some corners of UIView and round the view’s layer’s border too

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I am trying to round the bottom two corners of a UIView, and have the layer’s border show up rounded as well. I am currently doing:

```
UIRectCorners corners = UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
CGSize radii = CGSizeMake(kThisViewCornerRadius, kThisViewCornerRadius);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:myView.bounds
                                           byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                 cornerRadii:radii];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[maskLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
myView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

This works fine for normal views. However, `myView`’s layer has its `borderColor` and `borderWidth` set, and as you can see from the screenshot, the layer’s border is not getting rounded:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I also tried subclassing UIView and returning `[CAShapeLayer layer]` from `+[Class layerClass]`, and setting up the view’s layer *as* a shape layer, but the border ended up beneath the view’s subviews.

Is it possible to round some of a view’s corners, round the view’s layer’s border, and clip the subviews underneath the layer’s border?

Note that this is *not* about how to round some corners and not others, but rather how to get the stroke to behave correctly.

Comment: Add a shape layer that is stroked into the layer hierarchy?

Comment: Good suggestion, but I tested it and the shape layer’s stroke still shows up behind the view’s subviews.

Comment: Actually, your comment got me thinking on the right track, and I ended up getting it. I’ll post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounded UIView using CALayers - only some corners - How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I figured out a new way of thinking about it, thanks to [David Rönnqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608157/david-ronnqvist)’s comment.

I was trying to do the corner rounding and the stroke all in one layer. Instead, I broke it up into two layers: one to mask the view’s layer to round the corners, and the other in a view to add the stroke.

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];

UIRectCorners corners = UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
CGSize radii = CGSizeMake(kThisViewCornerRadius, kThisViewCornerRadius);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:myView.bounds
                                           byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                 cornerRadii:radii];

// Mask the container view’s layer to round the corners.
CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[cornerMaskLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
containerView.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;

// Make a transparent, stroked layer which will dispay the stroke.
CAShapeLayer *strokeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
strokeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
strokeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
strokeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
strokeLayer.lineWidth = 2; // the stroke splits the width evenly inside and outside,
                           // but the outside part will be clipped by the containerView’s mask.

// Transparent view that will contain the stroke layer
UIView *strokeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.bounds];
strokeView.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // in case your container view contains controls
[strokeView.layer addSublayer:strokeLayer];

// configure and add any subviews to the container view

// stroke view goes in last, above all the subviews
[containerView addSubview:strokeView];
```

Comment: very nice! But can i set optional borders with this?

Comment: What do you mean by optional borders?

Answer (score 11):

Zev Eisenberg's answer is the right one.

Although I prefer:

```
[self.layer addSublayer:strokeLayer];
```

instead of creating and adding a subview:

```
CGSize radii = CGSizeMake(radius, radius);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                           byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                 cornerRadii:radii];

// Mask the container view’s layer to round the corners.
CAShapeLayer *cornerMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[cornerMaskLayer setPath:path.CGPath];
self.layer.mask = cornerMaskLayer;

// Make a transparent, stroked layer which will dispay the stroke.
CAShapeLayer *strokeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
strokeLayer.path = path.CGPath;
strokeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
strokeLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
strokeLayer.lineWidth = 2; // the stroke splits the width evenly inside and outside,
// but the outside part will be clipped by the containerView’s mask.

[self.layer addSublayer:strokeLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small code. Alloc init a view and send to this method to get corners rounded. You can optionally round any of the corners u want. Also give shadow stroke color.

```
 -(void) setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withColor:  (UIColor*) color
{
 UIBezierPath* rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds  byRoundingCorners:corners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.0, 9.0)];

CAShapeLayer* shape = [[[CAShapeLayer alloc] init] autorelease];
[shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
shape.strokeColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

view.backgroundColor=color;
view.layer.mask = shape;
}
```

Call the method like this.

```
[self setMaskTo:ABCView byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners withColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```