# Selective round corners in image view - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I am working in Xcode Version 6.1.1 and iOS 8.1 to develop my app in which I need round top-left and top-right corners in an image view according to design.

I have used the following code before, and it works correctly in previous versions of Xcode:

```
UIImageView *locationImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

UIBezierPath *maskPath1;

maskPath1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:locationImage.bounds
                                  byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft)
                                        cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer1.frame = locationImage.bounds;
maskLayer1.path = maskPath1.CGPath;
locationImage.layer.mask = maskLayer1;
```

Now I get the top-left corner rounded but not the right one. I know the code is correct because if I apply it to a not constrained image view, it works well, but I need to constrain the items to the view. I use auto layout.

link to image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/orisd8gzbdhsr4z/round-corners.tiff?dl=0

There is something I am doing wrong? How can I round two corners properly?

Thanks in advance

*Sorry for my english

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round some corners of UIView and round the view’s layer’s border too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866450/round-some-corners-of-uiview-and-round-the-view-s-layer-s-border-too)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but the post related uses the same code to round the corners, just add a stroke (which I don´t need), and works in the same way: just rounding the top-left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution nesting the uiimageview in a uiview with corner radius set in the User Defined Runtime Attributes and setting the cliptobounds of this uiview to yes.

If anyone needs further explanation, I will give delighted

Answer (score 1):

@jcmartinac,

you can use this Solution -**[how to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview)**

in your Code apply this Code , i have tested , its working perfectly.

```
maskPath1 = (UIImageView *)[self roundCornersOnView: maskPath1 onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:NO bottomRight:NO radius:20.0];
```

//use below Method to Set Corner Radius Round..

```
-(UIView *)roundCornersOnView:(UIView *)view onTopLeft:(BOOL)tl topRight:(BOOL)tr bottomLeft:(BOOL)bl bottomRight:(BOOL)br radius:(float)radius {

    if (tl || tr || bl || br) {
        UIRectCorner corner = 0; //holds the corner
        //Determine which corner(s) should be changed
        if (tl) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopLeft;
        }
        if (tr) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerTopRight;
        }
        if (bl) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomLeft;
        }
        if (br) {
            corner = corner | UIRectCornerBottomRight;
        }

        UIView *roundedView = view;
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundedView.bounds byRoundingCorners:corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = roundedView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        roundedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        return roundedView;
    } else {
        return view;
    }

}
```

///////////// For TableVIew Use Below Code in cellForRowAtIndexPath Method /////

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.Img_thumb=(UIImageView *)[self roundCornersOnView: cell.Img_thumb onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:NO bottomRight:NO radius:20.0];
}
```

Check Screen Shot :-> [image: Effect on Table]

Comment: Thanks for helping! Unfortunately it works the same way before... Testing the code, I have realized that only works the top-left corner, if I try to round any other it does nothing. I am totally lost

Comment: I have seen your code works inside uiviewcontroller, but I am using uitableviewcontroller and is when it does not work. Did you try it in a uiimageview inside a cell in a uitableview? I think the problem is in uitableview

Comment: Yes, its working good in UITableView..

**cell.Img_thumb=(UIImageView *)[self roundCornersOnView: cell.Img_thumb onTopLeft:YES topRight:YES bottomLeft:NO bottomRight:NO radius:20.0];**

Comment: @jcmartinac, i have Update my Code , you can see this.

Comment: Hello and thanks again! I keep looking for solutions and have decided to attach a simple project to see clearly my problem by rounding the top corners of a UIImageView that occupies the entire width of a cell in a table. When I apply the code to do this, the image loses the screen width and it does not work for me. With this example I hope someone can help me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9i3ye2wb2ck0ef/roundcorners.zip?dl=0

Comment: i have Download your Code, & also try to solve your BUG but**i am not able to Create Right Side of TWO corner Round.**...i think you need **Expert Advice**..

i give my best. 
:)

Comment: @jcmartinac, If you find helpful please Upvote the Answer +1.