# CAShapeLayer with UIRectCornerBottomLeft/Right makes my view disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calayer, cashapelayer

OK.  I have done the Google search, the Stack search, the Wenderlich search (is that a meme yet?).  I have tried every thing here on overflow and nothing is working.

I need a CALayer expert.

I have a tableView that I'm showing as a dropdown from the top of my app.  It shows up fine and dandy until I try to round the bottom left/right corners.  Every attempt I have tried to do this has resulted in my table just disappearing entirely.  The methods still fire and I get my completions for the up/down methods.  However the table just disappears.

Code with a tableView:

```
- (void)setupTopMenu {
    CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

    self.topMenuTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth / 2) - ((screenWidth - topMenuSideBuffer) / 2), self.view.frame.origin.y + topBuffer, (screenWidth - topMenuSideBuffer), 0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.topMenuTable.backgroundColor = DARK_BLUE_NAVBAR_COLOR;
    self.topMenuTable.dataSource = self;
    self.topMenuTable.delegate = self;
    self.topMenuTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.topMenuTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    self.topMenuTable.separatorColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.topMenuTable.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.topMenuTable.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.topMenuTable.layer.borderWidth = 0.4f;

    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.topMenuTable.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    self.topMenuTable.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    [self.view addSubview:self.topMenuTable];
}
```

Code with just a view (I thought maybe it had something to do with the tableView but it behaves the same when I use a regular UIView)

```
- (void)setupTopMenu {
    CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

    self.topMenuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth / 2) - ((screenWidth - topMenuSideBuffer) / 2), self.view.frame.origin.y + topBuffer, (screenWidth - topMenuSideBuffer), 0)];
    self.topMenuView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.topMenuView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.topMenuView.layer.borderWidth = 0.4f;

    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.topMenuView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    self.topMenuView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    [self.view addSubview:self.topMenuView];
}
```

Code I'm using to show the view(s):

```
- (void)showTopMenu {

    if (!isTopMenuDown) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 animations:^ {
            //self.topMenuTable.frame = CGRectMake((self.screenWidth / 2) - (self.topMenuWidth / 2), self.view.bounds.origin.y + topBuffer, self.topMenuWidth, self.topMenuHeight);
            self.topMenuView.frame = CGRectMake((self.screenWidth / 2) - (self.topMenuWidth / 2), self.view.bounds.origin.y + topBuffer, self.topMenuWidth, self.topMenuHeight);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^ {
            // self.topMenuTable.frame = CGRectMake((self.screenWidth / 2) - (self.topMenuWidth /2), self.view.bounds.origin.y + topBuffer, self.topMenuWidth, 0);
            self.topMenuView.frame = CGRectMake((self.screenWidth / 2) - (self.topMenuWidth /2), self.view.bounds.origin.y + topBuffer, self.topMenuWidth, 0);
        } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }

    isTopMenuDown =! isTopMenuDown;
}
```

NOTE:  I have also tried the idea of adding the mask to the layer like in [Round some corners of UIView and round the view’s layer’s border too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866450/round-some-corners-of-uiview-and-round-the-view-s-layer-s-border-too)

Same result.

If I take out the Layer code the views show up perfectly but using the layer code makes them disappear.

Is there something about the way I'm showing the view that I can't see, that is making it disappear?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought maybe it had something to do with the tableView but it behaves the same when I use a regular UIView

Exactly so - because it has nothing to do with the table view. It has to do with the fact that you don't understand what a mask is.

A mask layer blocks out parts of its layer depending on the *transparency* of the mask layer. You have done nothing about distinguishing opaque parts of the mask from transparent parts. Your whole mask is transparent. Therefore, *all* of the layer - meaning, all of the view - is blocked out (invisible).

It seems to me you are describing something like this (I've exaggerated the rounding of the corners, just for display purposes):

[image]

That is a rectangle with a mask on it. The mask consists of a *filled* rounded rectangle path. Thus, the *interior* of the path is opaque, and appears; the exterior is transparent, and does not appear.

Just FYI, here's how I created the mask and added it (I used an image and `contents`, but you are certainly free to use a shape layer if you want to):

```
UIView* viewToMask = self.view.subviews[0];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewToMask.bounds.size, NO, 0);
UIBezierPath* round = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:viewToMask.bounds byRoundingCorners: (UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(50,50)];
[round fill];
UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
CALayer* mask = [CALayer new];
mask.frame = viewToMask.bounds;
mask.contents = (id)result.CGImage;
viewToMask.layer.mask = mask;
```