# Rounded bottom edge of UIView

Tags: uiview, uibezierpath

In App I have subclassed UINavigationBar and as my TitleView I'm setting(in View Controller) custom UIView

```
[self.playButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:self.playButton];
```

The bottom edge of this view (playButton) should be curved. Not only corners, bot whole bottom edge.To achieve this effect I'm using this code:

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

[path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.playButton.frame.size.width, self.playButton.frame.size.height)  controlPoint1:CGPointMake(0, self.playButton.frame.size.height) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(self.playButton.frame.size.width, 60)];
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
self.playButton.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

But after that code my UIView (playButton) dissapeared! Is this proper way to apply curved bottom edge of UIView?

It should looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLbSv.png

Comment: may be this is what you are trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how

Comment: They are talking about rounding corners, I want to round/curved whole bottom edge.

Comment: I think one probable reason would be you are forgetting to use movetopoint method which should ideally exist if the functions you use have endpoints specified. In addCurveToPoint method you need to specify the endpoints with the control points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
-(void)roundCorners:(UIRectCorner)corner radius:(float)radius
{   
    _cornerRadius = radius;
    _corner = corner;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [super drawRect:rect];

    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:_corner cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(_cornerRadius, _cornerRadius)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[maskLayer setFrame:self.playButton.bounds];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(self.playButton.center.x, -36.0) radius:65.5 startAngle:0 endAngle:2*M_PI clockwise:YES];


//[path closePath];
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
self.playButton.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I apply this mask my View (playButton) disappears from main view...

Comment: Please make sure that the play button frame is set.

Comment: Yes, frame is set, it code. And still my playButton disappears :(