# UIWebView round corners on only bottom side for iOS7

Tags: ios, uiwebview, quartz-core

I've got my webview rounding its corners out nicely:

```
   [[self.webView layer] setCornerRadius:4];
   [self.webView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

However I was looking to try and only round the bottom corners, and leave the top corners square. I found some old code from a few years ago on StackOverflow that uses layer masking, but its pretty old and I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a better/cleaner way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you see this answer to [Rounded UIView using CALayers - only some corners - How?][1]? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5826698/118091

Comment: I did, that code is from 2011 for iOS3.2. It might still work, but I think there might be new API methods available.