# UIBezierPath doesn't work in TopRight corner and BottomRight corner

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I want to round my right corners, but only works for Left corners

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopLeft, UIRectCorner.TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath
    view.layer.mask = maskLayer
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: I think you need to post more code because what you posted in itself is correct code.

Comment: Make sure the `bounds` is correct for the view you're applying corner radius to

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is that you're getting the view's bounds before it's been resized for the current device. It's larger than it will be later when it appears on screen, so the right side of your rounded rect is off the right side of the screen.

You need to create `path` and set `maskLayer.path` later, after the view has been resized, which means during or after the layout phase of the run loop. So either subclass the view and do it in the view's `layoutSubviews` method, or do it in the view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Thank you! I've wondered for quite some time why the left corners are rendered correctly but not the right ones.

Comment: This is really a bad bug!

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 3**

It works for me !

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.containerView.roundCorners(corners: [.topRight,.topLeft], radius: 25)
       self.containerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

You can check the method "roundCorners" here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41217863/3687902

Comment: This is precisely the logic for a UITableViewCell. Thank you so much. None of the other methods I tried worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are tried to set the RoundingCorners for View which are design on Storyboard OR Xib then please set the corner and MaskLayer.path into below method.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
// here you can write the code...
    }
```