# UIView corner issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have blue UIView and I want top corners.
This is my code:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.backgroundContentView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shapeLayer.frame = self.backgroundContentView.bounds;
shapeLayer.path  = path.CGPath;
self.backgroundContentView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

But I have only leftTop corner. Why?

[image]

Comment: It did not help. The result is the same

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/35685726/77567

Answer (score 0):

use this code to alloc memory to `CALayer`

`CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];`