# Applying mask to UITextView in order to round corners causes view to disappear

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview, uibezierpath

I have a `UITextField` subclass that contains a `UITextView` used to display some text below the `UITextField`.

I'm trying to round bottom two corners of the UITextView with the following code but for some reason it's disappearing.

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: textView.bounds, 
                      byRoundingCorners: ([.bottomRight, .bottomRight]), 
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = textView.bounds
maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
textView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Why?

I'm using AutoLayout to place the textView beneath the textField - perhaps AutoLayout is clashing with what I have going on here? Or am I not setting the maskLayer's coordinates correctly?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35811368/77567

Comment: That did it, thanks so much. I should have been thinking more about the view lifecycle while debugging.
by the way, one of the greatest SO answers of all time - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25768875/3354041