# How to corner radius only top left and top right of table view custom cell on Iphone +

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to corner radius only top left and top right of table view custom cell .I write following code and it working fine on iphone 6, 5,7 . but on Iphone 6+, 7+ it look like given screen.

My code is ----

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomeCell"];
 if (indexPath.row == 0) {        
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath
                                  bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.contantsView.bounds
                                  byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                  cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4, 4)
                                  ];

        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = cell.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        cell.contantsView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        cell.contantsView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    }


    return cell;
}
```

And my screen look like --: 
[image]

it this screen I corner radius of only first and last cell . Center cell are look fine . I want to look all cells width same .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set cornerRadius for only bottom-left,bottom-right and top-left corner of a UIView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616382/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-bottom-left-bottom-right-and-top-left-corner-of)

Comment: no I have deferent scenario , Please read carefully .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, the `cell.contentView.bounds` (and I assume your `contantsView` is inside that) is not the same as the `cell.bounds`. While you're setting the `frame` of your layer using the `bounds` of the `contantsView`, but when creating the `UIBezierPath` for your mask, you are using the `bounds` of the `cell`, itself. These are not the same (at the time of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, at least).

So, that suggests a couple of possible fixes:

- The simple fix is to `cell.bounds` rather than `cell.contantsView.bounds` when defining the bezier path. You're using one `CGRect` for the `path` of the shape layer and another for the `frame` of that same shape layer. You really should use the same `CGRect` for both, and `cell.bounds` doesn't suffer this weird size issue.
- The `frame` of the `contentView` of the cell changes after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. So the above fix just happens to work because `cell.bounds` doesn't change, whereas the `contentView` (and thus likely your `contantsView`) does.

  The correct fix is that you really should put the masking of the layer in the `layoutSubviews` for that view that you're masking. (This, by the way, will also make sure that the mask gets set appropriately if you change orientation on the device, as well as anything else that might change the dimensions of the `contentView`.)

  If you don't want to bother subclassing the `contantsView` and implementing `layoutSubviews` for that, you can, theoretically, put the masked background color on the cell itself, rather than on `contantsView`, and implement `layoutSubviews` in `CustomeCell`. (Frankly, that might be the right view to be applying this background to, anyway.) But at whatever view you apply the background color, the masking of the view's corners should really be happening in its `layoutSubviews`.