# How to curve top of a UIView using swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I gone through [How to curve the top of a UIView Controller in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153535/how-to-curve-the-top-of-a-uiview-controller-in-swift)

and made a view. Its attached below. I want to remove that back color from my view. I made a uiview in storyboard and assigned a custom class to that view.

[image: want to remove the black color]

my custom class is

```
class curvedView: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let color = UIColor(rgb: 0x285387)
    let y:CGFloat = 0
   // let curveTo:CGFloat = 50

    let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
    myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))

    myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 3))
    myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
    myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
    myBezier.close()
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.setLineWidth(2.0)

    color.setFill()
    myBezier.fill()
}}

extension UIColor {
convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
    assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
    assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
    assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

    self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

convenience init(rgb: Int) {
    self.init(
        red: (rgb >> 16) & 0x28,
        green: (rgb >> 8) & 0x53,
        blue: rgb & 0x87
    )
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well simply give backgroundColor to that customview.

Like:

```
class curvedView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
     }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let color = UIColor(rgb: 0x285387)
        let y:CGFloat = 0
        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
        myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 3))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
        myBezier.close()
        color.setFill()
        myBezier.fill()
    }
}
```

or alternatively its better to give that in initialisation:

```
class curvedView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let color = UIColor(rgb: 0x285387)
        let y:CGFloat = 0
        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
        myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: rect.height / 3))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height))
        myBezier.close()
        color.setFill()
        myBezier.fill()

    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    }
}
```