# Create a UIView with rounded bottom edge

Tags: swift, view, rounded-corners

I want make view this Bottom rounded[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlpNA.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is really close to what you want:

The rectView is your initial view;
You can play with the + 50 of quad curve height to adjust the curve

```
let rectView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
    rectView.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview(rectView)

    let arcBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    arcBezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rectView.frame.height))
    arcBezierPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rectView.frame.width, y: rectView.frame.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rectView.frame.width / 2 , y: rectView.frame.height + 50 ))
    arcBezierPath.close()

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    shapeLayer.path = arcBezierPath.cgPath

    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    rectView.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
    rectView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    rectView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    rectView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    rectView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    rectView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    rectView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
```

Maybe, **even better**:
 You can create your view:

```
let rectView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
view.addSubview(rectView)
```

**Extend UIView**

```
extension UIView {
    func addBottomArc(ofHeight height: CGFloat, topCornerRadius: CGFloat) {
       let arcBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
       arcBezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.height))
       arcBezierPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: frame.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2 , y: frame.height + height ))
       arcBezierPath.close()

       let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

       shapeLayer.path = arcBezierPath.cgPath
       shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

       layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
       layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
       layer.cornerRadius = topCornerRadius
    }
}
```

So you can set the height and the corner radius like this:

```
rectView.addBottomArc(ofHeight: 50, topCornerRadius: 15)
```

and than add the shadow you need to your view:

```
    rectView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    rectView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    rectView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    rectView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
```