# Amazing corner radius outside color issue

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, calayer, cornerradius

This is code that I added to new view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100)];
    [contentView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:contentView];

    [[contentView layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
    [[contentView layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [[contentView layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [[contentView layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
}
```

The result:

[image]

If look at the corners we can see outside blue pixels:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CAShapeLayer :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:contentView];

    CAShapeLayer *subLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    [subLayer setFillColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
    [subLayer setStrokeColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
    [subLayer setLineWidth:6.0];
    [subLayer setPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:contentView.bounds cornerRadius:5.0].CGPath];

    [contentView.layer addSublayer:subLayer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is happening is that a clipping mask is being applied to the layer constraining it to the corner radii, and then the border is being drawn within that (over the top) of the background image, and due to a common technique called anti-aliasing you can see some of the pixels below.  Anti-aliasing is the technique used to try to prevent round and angular lines from looking jagged.

Edit:

As per my last comment, if you want to keep it all in one view, make the border transparent or width 0 for the bottom layer (with the blue) to get the rounded corners, then create as 2nd layer slightly larger that draws the border, making sure the view frame is large enough to accommodate the drawn 
border.

Comment: alos antialiasing it's ok but i think for internal arcs. so as for jagged and outside antialiasing it should use white color or transparent I don't know

Comment: What happens when you tweak the border width by very small amounts? Does it have any impact? What about if you change the color tones by very small fractional amounts?  If your particular application is so sensitive to that small amount of pixel bleed, maybe you can simply create the clipping mask for the CA layer that has the background blue so that the corners are rounded off, drawing it without an opaque border, then superimpose another layer slightly larger that is transparent except for a drawn border.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it looks like apple draws the background and the border separately with already rounded corners on each other. You can get the same result when drawing two identical rounded rect bezier paths over each other with different background colors.
It's caused by Antialiasing of both drawn elements.

A solution that worked for me so far:
Use 2 different views inside a containerView. One with the border and a clear background, the other with the background color.
Use the cornerRadius on both subviews, but the background view should be inset by a half pixel:

```
CGRectMake(borderView.frame.origin.x + 0.5,
           borderView.frame.origin.y + 0.5,
           borderView.frame.size.width - 1.0,
           borderView.frame.size.height - 1.0);
```

That way you shouldn't see the antialiased pixels at the edges of the border.

Comment: yep make it a little bit smaller solves the issue also u found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264083/rounded-uiview-using-calayers-only-some-corners-how)