# UITableViewCell margin left and right

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, margin

I would like to make cells like this. I use swift.

But I do not know how to add margins on the right and left sides of the cell.

Do you know how to do the same edge effect rounds the section? (When there are several cells, the edges in contact are not rounded)
[image]

When i use the contentInset :

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 0)
```

[image]

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -15)
```

[image]

Comment: try this `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, -15)`

Comment: it works at right but not at left...

Comment: customize the coordinates , surely works

Comment: self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)

Comment: when I put a left margin, it is right.

Comment: You can add a UIView as the white background of your cell and use a UIBezierPath to round just the top or bottom corners of your view.  Use the answers on this question as a guideline: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2264083/3543861

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your screenshots it looks like you're trying to do this with a grouped table view. To do this you should use a `UITableView` added to a `UIViewController` not a `UITableViewController`.

To set the inset you should just set constraints/frame of your table view to be slightly in from the left and right edge  and set your view's background color to `UIColor.groupTableViewBackgroundColor()`

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can say something like:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cornerRadius:CGFloat = 5.0

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure your cell

        let sectionCount = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        cell.layer.mask = nil
        if sectionCount > 1
        {

            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                var bounds = cell.bounds
                bounds.origin.y += 1.0
                let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius,height: cornerRadius))
                shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath
                cell.layer.mask = shapeLayer
            case sectionCount - 1:
                var bounds = cell.bounds
                bounds.size.height -= 1.0
                let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.BottomLeft, .BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius,height: cornerRadius))
                shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath
                cell.layer.mask = shapeLayer
            default:
                break
            }
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectInset(cell.bounds,0.0,2.0), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
            shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath
            cell.layer.mask = shapeLayer
            return cell
        }
    }
```

You just apply a mask based on the index path of the row and the number of rows in the section. If you have dynamically sized cells you will likely need to move applying the mask to your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

You should get a result like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 13.0 there is a new tableview style "Inset grouped" that exactly does this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/insetgrouped